# write to XML with RapidXML

Tags: c++, xml, rapidxml

I am trying to read my vector with tuple and parse it in to a xml file.
The writing to the XML file works but he only write the values of the
last 
node. So i get only the same values all time.
I found that after the for loop he loosing all existing nodes. Maybe my idea with doc.append_node(root) is wrong?!

```
    #include "XmlHandle.h"
    #include <rapidxml/rapidxml.hpp>
    #include "rapidxml/rapidxml_print.hpp"
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sstream>

    using namespace rapidxml;

    XmlHandle::WriteToXml(std::vector<std::tuple<Key, Tone>> vector)
    {
        xml_document<> doc;
        xml_node<>* decl = doc.allocate_node(node_declaration);
        //adding attributes at the top of our xml
        decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("version", "1.0"));
        decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("encoding", "utf-8"));
        doc.append_node(decl);
        //creating a pointer for the root note "NoteList"
        xml_node<> *root = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "NoteList");

        //iterating through our vector 
        for (std::tuple<Key, Tone> tuple : vector)
        {
            //creating the nodes tuple and key
            xml_node<> *tuple1 = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "Tuple");
            xml_node<> *key = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "Key");
            //getting the char of key saving in d
            char d = std::get<0>(tuple).key;
            //creating a pointer on d
            key->value(&d, 1);
            const char *name = std::string("test").c_str();
            //creating a new node element Tone
            xml_node<> *ToneNode = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "Tone");
            //adding the element to tuple1
            tuple1->append_node(ToneNode);
            //adding the note element Frequency
            xml_node<> *Frequency = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "Frequency");
            float FrequencyFloat = std::get<1>(tuple).frequency;
            std::string FrequencyString = std::to_string(FrequencyFloat);
            //setting the value from frequency
            Frequency->value(FrequencyString.c_str());
            tuple1->append_node(Frequency);
            xml_node<> *Node = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "Node");
            char * NodeValuePinter = (char*)&std::get<1>(tuple).tone;
            char *charPinter = &std::get<1>(tuple).tone;
            Node->value(charPinter, 1);
            ToneNode->append_node(Node);
            tuple1->append_node(key);
            //adding tuple to our root
            root->append_node(tuple1);

        }
        doc.append_node(root);
        std::string xml_as_string;
        rapidxml::print(std::back_inserter(xml_as_string), doc);
        std::ofstream fileStored("file_stored.xml");
        fileStored << xml_as_string;
        fileStored.close();
        doc.clear();
    }
```

Comment: That's a _lot_ of code. Can you present your [MCVE]?

Comment: It's also a lot of pointers. Ensure you're right about ownership semantics of everything you're adding.

Comment: Just to note, this is the opposite of 'parsing'. Parsing converts a textual representation to a data structure. You're going the other way ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem's probably here.

```
        char d = std::get<0>(tuple).key;
        key->value(&d, 1);
```

RapidXML stores the pointer you pass to value(), not the string it points to. So each time ound the loop your "value" points to the same thing - 'd'.

You should use `key->value(doc.allocate_string(&d, 1))` to add a copy of the character data to the key. The same, later for `node->value`.

[Rapidxml is writing wrong characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162661/rapidxml-is-writing-wrong-characters?rq=1)

It's absolutely the #1 RapidXML gotcha.